# How can I join two tables in mysql, so that whenever I add data to table 1, table 2 updates as well?

Tags: mysql, java

This is the code creating my first table

```
create table Todo_tbl (
id INT auto_increment,
person VARCHAR(45) ,
task VARCHAR(45) ,
duration INT(4),
deadline_day VARCHAR(2),
deadline_month VARCHAR(2),

PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into Todo_tbl values(1,'John', 'dust the floors', 40,04,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(2,'Matt', 'do the dishes', 15,02,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(3,'Mary', 'dusting', 40,03,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(4,'Chloe', 'cleaning the windows', 75,04,05);
insert into Todo_tbl values(5,'John', 'wash the floors', 60,03,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(6,'Bridget', 'take out the trash', 15,03,03);
insert into Todo_tbl values(7,'Matt', 'do the laundry', 18,02,02);
insert into Todo_tbl values(8,'Bridget', 'water the plants', 15,03,03);
```

This is the code for my second table:

```
create table Statistics_tbl (
SELECT person, SUM(duration) as total_duration FROM Todo_tbl GROUP BY person
);
```

As you can see, table one is built based on the data from Todo_tbl. The issue is that whenever I add data to the Todo_tbl, the values in the Statistics_tbl do not change. How can I join the two tables, so that whenever I input new data to Todo_tbl, the Statistics_tbl automatically reacts?

Comment: *whenever I input new data to Todo_tbl, the Statistics_tbl automatically reacts* Makes no sense. Obtain total_duration in the query when you really need in this data.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I am a beginner, so I am not sure how to use a trigger

Comment: @Akina the thing is that I want the total_duration that is held in one table to automatically include variables held in the other table. The code I included above creates the table which does it, the thing is that it does not read the newly added data

Comment: Study "Over-defined data - pros and cons". Create not a table but a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-syntax.html)  as @Akina mentioned in the comments.

```
create view Statistics_tbl as SELECT person, 
                              SUM(duration) as total_duration 
                              FROM Todo_tbl 
                              GROUP BY person;
```

You can use it as a table:

```
select * from Statistics_tbl;
```

Result:

```
person  total_duration
John       100
Matt       33
Mary       40
Chloe      75
Bridget    30
```

Comment: thank you so much, it is working!