# I cannot create a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, java

```
create table Statistics_tbl with (
SELECT Todo_tbl.person, SUM(Todo_tbl.duration) FROM Todo_tbl JOIN Statistics_tbl 
on Todo_tbl.person = Statistics_tbl.person GROUP BY person;
);
```

The issue is that the code above does not allow me to create a table Statistics_tbl that would be joined to the other table Todo_tbl.

> The issues reported are:
>
> - "')' is not valid at this position. Expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN"
> - "'(' is not valid at this position. Expecting an identifier.

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d5c0e48993306b3ac6db0fe6ecb5a43)

Comment: create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with the underlying tables and update your post with the url

Comment: Meanwhile, you are trying to create a table defined in terms of itself. Also, the syntax is not valid, perhaps you should describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Lennart https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d5c0e48993306b3ac6db0fe6ecb5a43

Comment: Maybe you needed `INSERT INTO` instead of `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table Statistics_tbl (person VARCHAR(45), sum_duration INT)
    SELECT Todo_tbl.person, SUM(Todo_tbl.duration) sum_duration
    FROM Todo_tbl
    GROUP BY person;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff57cb2a8755e2c2ee8136e75c47bd38

Answer (score 0):

After I re-reading the answers and comments in [how-can-i-join-two-tables-in-mysql-so-that-whenever-i-add-data-to-table-1-tabl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307079/how-can-i-join-two-tables-in-mysql-so-that-whenever-i-add-data-to-table-1-tabl/307085#307085) I think you are looking for a Materialized Query Table (MQT). AFAIK these do not exist in MySQL but you can create your own Incremental Evaluation System (IES) via triggers, see for example: https://fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

I added a small example for an insert trigger at: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb04640727e19a430a1df4269051a423). You will have to add corresponding ones for update and delete. Needless to say, you also need to add keys and not null constraints in your tables so that rows can be safely identified. Disclaimer, I don't know MySQL that well, so I can't tell what concurrency problems (such as lost update) you may have to take into consideration

What is the problem with the view suggested in the previous answer?